# Running grunt-nodemon and watch concurrently with livereload

Tags: node.js, angularjs, gruntjs

So the problem I'm having is with grunt-nodemon and watch runned concurrently, everything works except browser livereload.

If I run watch without concurrent, everything works just fine, but then nodewatch doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did solve this question after some hours spent digging. I solved it by spawning child process for the nodemon. If you have some troubles I'm happy to help.

```
grunt.registerTask('serve', function (target) {
    if (target === 'dist') {
        return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
    }

    // Running nodejs in a different process and displaying output on the main console
    var nodemon = grunt.util.spawn({
        cmd: 'grunt',
        grunt: true,
        args: 'nodemon'
    });

    nodemon.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
    nodemon.stderr.pipe(process.stderr);

    grunt.task.run([
        'clean:server',
        'bowerInstall',
        'concurrent:server',
        'autoprefixer',
        'connect:livereload',
        'watch',
        ]);
});
```

Comment: Hello, can you help me to solve this problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35079667/grunt-nodemon-same-port-issue